# Описание CNN слоев и функций активации

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Есть такой код:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Что делает тут Dense и Dropout
2. Значение параметров relu и
       softmax у Dense в последних строках
3. Почему последняя строка с `Dense` использует `softmax`, а не `relu`,например (или это не имеет значения?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по архитектуре данной НС - это сверточная НС, для классификации картинок с одним цветовым каналом (градации серого) размером 28 x 28 пикселей. Классифицируются 10 различных объектов / классов - это следует из последнего (выходного) слоя с 10 нейронами и функцией активации `softmax`.

`softmax` возвращает вероятность принадлежности картинки к каждому классу. Т.е. на выходе получается матрица с 10-ю столбцами (один столбец на каждый класс) с вероятностями.

Слой `Dense` - это простой полносвязный слой, когда каждый нейрон предыдущего слоя связан с каждым нейроном данного. Обычно во всех сверточных сетях в последних слоях используют 2-3 полносвязных слоя, которые следуют за слоями свертки, пулинга и "выпрямления" (слой: `Flatten`).

слой `Flatten` - "выпрямляет" 2+-мерные матрицы в одномерные вектора. Например из матрицы размерности `(64, 32, 32)` получится одномерный вектор с `64 * 32 * 32 = 65536` элементов.

`Dropout` - один из методов регуляризации (используется для борьбы с переобучением).

`relu` - одна из самых популярных нелинейных функций активации нейронов:

```
f(x) = max(0, x)
```

Comment: Лучше скажите что делает Flatten)

Comment: А MaxPooling2D я как понимаю выдёргивает фичи из тензора полученного от Conv2D?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, хороший совет, спасибо! Добавил в ответ

Comment: @MaxU, Да,это НС для классификации цифр mnist в данном случае.Спасибо за ответ, очень помогли)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, `MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))` проплывает окошком размером `(2, 2)` по матрице и для каждого окошка выбирает максимальное значение, уменьшая размер исходной матрицы